# Is it possible to use Whoosh search in a serverless environment?

Tags: python, api, amazon-web-services, lambda, whoosh

I'm trying to set up Whoosh search in a serverless environment (aws lambda hosted api) and having trouble with Whoosh since it hosts the index on the local filesystem. That becomes an issue with containers that aren't able to update and reference a single index.

Does anyone know if there is a solution to this problem. I am able to select the location that the directory is hosted but it has to be on the local filesystem. Is there a way to represent an s3 file as a local file?

I'm currently having to reindex every time the app is initialized and while it works it's clearly an expensive and terrible workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be no. Serverless environments by default are ephemeral and don't support persistent data storage which is needed for something like storing an index that Whoosh generates.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use Whoosh in RAM.

```py
from whoosh.filedb.filestore import RamStorage

store = RamStorage()
ix = store.create_index(...)
```